# How to track user views for a post in Django?

Tags: django

ObjectViewed model is for tracking users view in post. I am trying to filter number of views for a specific post of the author

```
            models.py
class ObjectViewed(models.Model):
    user            =       models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address      =       models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)
    content_type    =       models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id       =       models.PositiveIntegerField() # User id, Blog id, or any other models id
    content_object  =       GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    timestamp       =       models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s viewed by %s on %s' %(self.content_object, self.user, self.timestamp)

views.py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model       =       Post
    template_name=      'edmin/post/postDetail.html'
    context_object_name='posts'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        post=Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        print(content_type)
        context['obj_view'] = ObjectViewed.objects.filter(content_type=content_type,
object_id=self.request.user.id)
        print(context['obj_view'])
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_object` method in DetailView class by adding a `view_count` modelfiled into model whose viewcount you need, then you can use below code in that model detail view.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    ......
    ......
   def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.view_count += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: sir, can you explain view_count elaborately because i am not getting it. I am actually a beginner in django

Comment: you have to count the Number of views for the post, which uses Post model and view that using DetailView. For that when ever we redirect to detail view page the count needs to be updated that can be done by above get_object method . When the view is opened, In background it gets the view object from get_object method. so what we are doing is before feeding the method we are updating count of a variable of that particular object. this can be done by including view_count in your post model keep it null and blank true with default = 0  and exclude input in form so it gets updated in background

Comment: as i can see you are using to inject it into context its a bit complicated comparatively you ned to understand the workflow for that you can do not need to add variable you can just simple display it as {{post.related_name.count}} in you template as you are logging data of vied user.. again its bit easy when you get the work flow.